# How to create EntityFrameworkCore Custom data provider?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement from my client. he want a custom data provider for EntityFrameWrok Core which is similar to like In Memory approach.
We have service fabric stateless gateway endpoints which internally call to stateful service to get the data or update the data similar to SQL server.
But we have different data stores like cosmos db, SQL server , service fabric reliable dictionary. He want to change the provider based on the requirement.
the requirement is like if he want to store data in SQL server he will add SQL server provider in startup similar to remaining.

We have SQL server and cosmos db providers by default, but we don't have provider for service fabric reliable dictionaries, so we want to create custom provider on top of service fabric reliable dictionaries.

I didn’t find much details about creating custom provider, So can anyone direct me where to start and how to do that.I would be better if any documents or links samples etc.

Thanks ,
Srinivas Velpula.

Answer (score -2):

Although it's a bit out of date, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/writing-a-provider) shows how to write a provider, and the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore) is available if you need to see how to do it.  (first hit on Google "ef core custom provider").

Comment: Hey Neil, I gone through them and also googled some time, That's why I posted here for the help, I'm unable to find correct root. If you have any please direct me. 
I gone through the links which you have shared before.